# Select from table and insert into another table

Tags: java, mysql

I tried to select some data from a MYSQL database tab and insert them into another MYSQL database table.

This is my servlet code

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String name = request.getParameter("name");

    ArrayList al = null;

    int size = 0;
    size = AcceptDao.getData(name);

    if (size>0) {
        out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        out.println("alert('Successfully Employee Added');");
        out.println("</script>");
    } else {
        out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        out.println("alert('Try Again');");
        out.println("</script>");
    }
}
```

and here is my java code to do select and insert data.

```
 public static int getData(String Uname) {
    ArrayList al = null;
    int status = 0;
    String name = null;
    String role = null;
    String pass = null;
    try {
        Connection con = ConnectionProvider.getCon();
        String query = "SELECT noty_name,noty_user_role,noty_pass FROM notification WHERE noty_name='" + Uname + "'";

        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        al = new ArrayList();

        while (rs.next()) {
            name = rs.getString("noty_name");
            role = rs.getString("noty_user_role");
            pass = rs.getString("noty_pass");

        }

            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO employee (name,user_role,pass) values(?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, name);
            ps.setString(2, role);
            ps.setString(3, pass);
            status = ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return status;
}
```

this isn't work properly. this code doesn't do select and insert. What is the wrong with this code.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Using `e.printStackTrace()` in the `catch` block, please check if there is any exception.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the code part for **"insert"** is outside the loop. So only the last data in the loop will be inserted, if available. 
Moreover there is no need of `while(rs.next)` loop. you can use `if(rs.next)` condition if you are sure that you be passing a unique name in the request.

```
while (rs.next()) {
   name = rs.getString("noty_name");
   role = rs.getString("noty_user_role");
   pass = rs.getString("noty_pass");    
}
/* The Below part is wrong */
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO employee (name,user_role,pass) values(?,?,?)");
ps.setString(1, name);
ps.setString(2, role);
ps.setString(3, pass);
status = ps.executeUpdate();
```

Instead use this below code

```
public static int getData(String Uname) {
ArrayList al = null;
int status = 0;
String name = null;
String role = null;
String pass = null;
try {
    Connection con = ConnectionProvider.getCon();
    String query = "SELECT noty_name,noty_user_role,noty_pass FROM notification WHERE name='" + Uname + "'";

    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    al = new ArrayList();

    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO employee (name,user_role,pass) values(?,?,?)");

    while (rs.next()) {
        name = rs.getString("noty_name");
        role = rs.getString("noty_user_role");
        pass = rs.getString("noty_pass");

        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.setString(2, role);
        ps.setString(3, pass);
        status = ps.executeUpdate();
    }


} catch (Exception e) {
}
return status;
```

}

Comment: Thank you people for helping me out. I found the solution. :)